# How to pick specific words from data-attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pick specific words from a data attribute for a web application… is this possible?

---

Needs to keep spaces…

1. Choosing the first word
2. Choosing the last word
3. Choosing the word that comes before…
4. Choosing the word that comes after…
5. Choosing everything that comes before…
6. Choosing everything that comes after…

---

The data attribute value can easily change from…

- Im picking a certain word from this value
- to
- Im not just picking a certain word from the selected menu above

```js
//Must keep spaces

alert('');// Alert the first word from data-nick-picking
// Answer - Im

alert('');// Alert the last word from data-nick-picking
// Answer - value

alert('');// Alert the word that comes before the word this
// Answer - from

alert('');// Alert the word that comes after the word picking
// Answer - a

alert('');// Alert everything before the word certain 
// Answer - Im picking a

alert('');// Alert everything after the word from
// Answer - this value





// Please no cheating or beating around the bush… the amount of words can change for before or after a word example
// Alert everything before the word certains answer
// Could change to
// Im not just picking a

// or

// Alert everything after the word from answer
// Could change to
// the selected menu above
```

```html
<div data-nick-picking="Im picking a certain word from this value" class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: This looks very... "Homework". What have you tried?

Comment: No… it's not home work… I building a web application

Comment: And Im using the data attribute… but I need to pick certain words from the value… but I'm not exactly sure how its done

Comment: I'll state this above… so I don't confuse anyone

Comment: "Please no cheating" - Looks homework to me. Anyway, not arguing with you, no-one is judging if it is, just show us what you have tried and not understood, your expected output and what actually was output. Also, `alert()` is a really crappy way of doing this because it stops the flow. use `console.log(var)` instead and use the browser developer tools to read output.

Comment: Please make some attempt before seeking help. I'm finding it hard to understand how you plan to make this function. Where and how you want to select this "certain" word, where is this "certain word" coming from... a minimal example of your logic behind the functionality would no doubt help get a solid answer to your question.

Comment: Well I didn't want anyone to do actual work… So I just posted this

Comment: What I'm trying to build is a very advance data-if=""

Comment: data-if="body is scrolled 500px then add class to #box1"

Comment: How is the question in any way whatsoever related to that data-if comment? Also, @NewToJS - Don't just yet, I'm interested to see what he has accomplished so far and how the data-if comment is related to the homework question

Comment: Ok… thank you guys… sorry for bothering you… Someone else is trying to help me

Comment: Ok guys look… Its a straight forward question… I'm actually building something way… Way… WAY more advanced that the question… the question is just a way for me to get my feet wet to build that web application

Comment: @DanWhite Well the `data-if`="body is scrolled... appears to be heading into a completely new question based on scroll position which has nothing to do with this existing question. I can see this post being more work than it needs to be .

Comment: Thats just it… I can figure that out you guys don't need to do all of that… I can do that

Comment: I just need a push… Thats it… A push… not an arguement

Comment: @MonwellPartee if the question is so straight forward then why haven't you got a minimal example or able to explain where and how this "certain word" is given to the function to be used? Also I'm not looking to argue, I'm trying to get the relevant information to enable the possibility of offering a solid answer rather than me wasting time writing a answer assuming "I think this is what you want" sort of answer.

Comment: example… data-if="body is scrolled 500px add class .red to #box3"

Comment: data-if="clicked remove .transform"

Comment: data-if="this has the class .blue remove it and add class green"

Comment: I can figure all that out I just need to know how to select what I'm looking for

Comment: Why does this sound like homework? It's a question of how to select a certain value or values

Comment: @MonwellPartee but those are actions, changes to the element... no search for a "certain word" would be related to those actions explained. It's this simple... either explain your logic and I will be happy to try help.... until you take the time to plan your question and explain your logic I wish you the very best in getting the help.

Comment: As I was saying before…

Comment: All I needed was a little push

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/monwellpartee/dgod9f1j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assure that the value of your `data-if` does not have repetitive occurrences of a given word than this would be a pretty simple task, by simply converting the value of `data-if` to an array and using `indexOf` with `splice` or `slice` on the array.

Here is an example

```js
var data = "Im picking a certain word from this value".split(' ')

// first word
console.log(data[0])

// last word
console.log(data[data.length - 1])

// word before 'this'
console.log(data[data.indexOf('this') - 1])

// everything before the word 'certain'
console.log(data.splice(0, [data.indexOf('certain')]).join(' '))

// everything after the word 'from'
console.log(data.slice([data.indexOf('form') - 1]).join(' '))
```

But i'm afraid, that this will not be a very good decision to make. Maybe you need to overthink your logic on how the `data-if` should actually work. The `if` should probably, or most likely check if a given condition evaluates to `true` or `false`. This is a pretty hard decision to make, if all you have is a given string, which potentially could have a bunch of characters which will not meet the rules on how you decide if the outcome is `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank You… You have no Idea

Comment: The question isn't that hard… It's a simple question

Comment: OK, cool. Would really be interested on how you are going to solve this. If this will be an open source lib, let me know when you are done with it. Glad i could help you out somehow. ;)

Comment: It's not a true or false logic… the logic will be highly complex… I already have a working prototype of the logic working

Comment: But with this… I can now inject certain words within the logic from a sentence

Comment: prototype exampe…

Comment: var scroll = $($this.data("scrolled-target")).scrollTop();
     if (scroll >= $this.data('when-scrolled')) {
      $this.addClass($this.data('add-class'));
     } 
     else {
      $this.removeClass($this.data('add-class'));
     }

Comment: Oh, OK i think i know what you aiming for. Sound great.

Comment: now instead of using data-scrolled-target, data-add-class

Comment: Now i can just pick certain words to use… just pick and choose

Comment: So it is more like a little API inside the `data` attribute. Cool.

Comment: Exactly… but it won't just do scroll

Comment: when clicked………

Comment: when hovered………

Comment: Mouseover………………

Comment: I've got everything all set up… I just needed to know how specific words

Comment: for example… if(this sentence has the word load) {use the load logic and execute what the sentence is talking about}

Comment: I just needed the words

Comment: Another example

Comment: if ($this.data('load-file-into')) {
  if ($this.data('load-content')) {
   $(this.getAttribute('data-load-file-into')).load(this.getAttribute("data-load-file") + ' ' + this.getAttribute("data-load-content"));
  }
  else {
   $(this.getAttribute('data-load-file-into')).load(this.getAttribute("data-load-file"));
  }
 }

Comment: Here is the working prototype… Go into the HTML and change some of the values and make them your own…

Comment: The whole point of this is to use sentences to tell your browser what to do

Answer (score 0):

You could break the sentence into an array and then search for individual word matches. The first and last word will be the first and last array elements. To search for next or previous words, iterate over the array and once a match is found, choose the next or previous array item. You can always reform the array after you are finished with the join() function.

```
var words, search, result;

// break sentence

words = $('.wrapper').data('nick-picking').split(' ');
search = 'from';
result = '';

// search array

for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === search && i != words.length-1) {
    result = words[i+1]
  }
}

// rejoin sentence

words = words.join(' ');

// print result

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ok… thanks… I'm going to try and see if I can me this work

Comment: This is awesome… I can now choose the words before and after…

Comment: This is beyond awsome…

Comment: Now I can only guess that In order to get the first and last word… I need to find out how many is in the array example 0-7

Comment: Then I console.log(0) or console.log(7)

Comment: And then… If I know how many are in and array and I can choose (i+1) which will be equal to (5)

Comment: and if I know (5) and there are (7 arrays) then I just need to say… console.log(5 - 7)

Comment: but the problem is… how do I get the total number in the array that is capable of change? one may be (0-7) but another sentence may be (0-17)